# Redefine description environment

Tags: formatting

I tried using the Springer svmono class, but I don't like it. So I opened it and took some commands that could better format my document and inserted them into my tex document. However, they are already defined in the package I'm using (book package) and it gives me an error.

How can I redefine the environment description like the springer one?

```
% labels of description
\renewcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace\labelsep #1\hfil}

% adjusted environment "description"
% if an optional parameter (at the first two levels of lists)
% is present, its width is considered to be the widest mark
% throughout the current list.
\def\description{\@ifnextchar[{\@describe}{\list{}{\labelwidth\z@
            \labelsep=12pt\relax  %!!!!!!!!!
            \leftmargini=12pt\relax  %!!!!!!!!!
            \leftmargin=12pt\relax  %!!!!!!!!!
            \itemindent-\leftmargin \let\makelabel\descriptionlabel}}}
%
\def\describelabel#1{#1\hfil}
\def\@describe[#1]{\labelsep=12pt\relax
    \relax\ifnum\@listdepth=0
    \setitemindent{#1}\else\ifnum\@listdepth=1
    \setitemitemindent{#1}\fi\fi
    \list{--}{\let\makelabel\describelabel}}
```

Comment: Could you post an example of how Springer's descriptions look like? I'm pretty sure it can be done with `enumitem`.

Comment: Check this book. PDF page 18. http://www.sso.sy/sites/default/files/Complex%20Numbers%20from%20A%20to%20...%20Z%20%28Titu%20Andreescu%2C%20Dorin%20Andri.pdf

Comment: This is a Birkhäuser book! You mean `Solution`?

Comment: I mean the "Notations" on page 18 are made using description environment. How can I replicate that?

Comment: Do you mean list in Solution? This is simple enumerate. With use of the `enumitem` package you can write `\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*),leftmargin=*] `

Comment: This is not the same thing. Those lists are made in description environment. As you can see, there is some vertical alignment before the explanation of the symbols.